# How to have a random repeat?

Tags: c#, random

How can I repeat a random over and over until a bool becomes true and have it save all the randoms before it?
My random is:

```
Random random = new Random();
int colorFlash = random.Next(1, 5);
```

My bool is:

```
bool winner = false
```

Comment: you are showing partial code for example how and where is `random` declared. also what do you mean `until a bool becomes true` what bool are you talking about where are you checking this bool..? you need to be a lot more clearer on what you are wanting / trying to do..

Comment: Please show the entire code block, including any loop you are doing.

Comment: Have you considered a `while` loop?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the people in the comments that there's quite a lot of information missing, so I filled in the blanks:

```
        var allRandoms = new List<int>();
        bool winner = false;

        Random random = new Random();

        while(!winner)
        {
            int colorFlash = random.Next(1, 5);

            winner = (colorFlash == 4);

            allRandoms.Add(colorFlash);
        }
```

I've set up a list 'allRandoms' to capture all of the random numbers generated.
I've created a while loop that will continue until winner is true.
I've added a condition in my while loop that will set 'winner' to true if colorFlash equals 4, just so we can eventually break out of the while loop. You'll probably need a better way of ending this loop, but it will have to do for this example.
You can then run through each of your 'allRandoms' with the following:

```
            foreach(var i in allRandoms)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(i);
            }
```

---

Edit:
Just as a caveat, this will add all the random numbers including the random number that we stopped on in to the 'allRandoms' list.

Answer (score 0):

Save the colourFlashes in a collection, and use a while loop for the until. Alternatively, use a [do-while loop](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/370s1zax.aspx) if you always want at least one iteration.

```
//Create a collection to save our results
var colorFlashes = new List<int>();

while (winner == false)
{
  colorFlashes.Add(random.Next(1, 5));
}
```